# How to optimize the email AMPscript code that has a lot of lookups?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, email-template, content-builder

I have built a dynamic email template. This email template pulls the data from the Data Extension based on email name ( example: subject line, pre-header, content area, headers etc).
For each field that I am fetching from the content Data Extension I use a lookup.
Example:

```
set @subject            = Lookup(@ContentDataExtension,"subject","emailName",@emailName)
```

similarly I do around 30 lookups to fetch data.

I read that if there are a lot of lookups it might slow down the email processing & sends.

Steps which I have taken so far to optimize the code,

1. moved the lookups from email into a separate content block. Now in the email , I just call the content block. Does this make any difference?

Does anyone know how to optimize the code when doing multiple lookups from the same data extension or is there a better way I should handle this?

PS: I don't want to store the content data in a send data extension and just use Attribute value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create one central Content Data Extension and then pull from it all the needed 30 fields based on the email name using [LookupRows](https://ampscript.guide/lookuprows/) AMPScript function. That would be definitely more efficient than 30 separate Lookups.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense